# How to convert a string `to_json` and `to_xml` using Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, json, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I would like, in some way, to convert a string `to_json` and `to_xml`.

Just to know, I need to return that string in a Rack method in this way:

```
[404, {"Content-type" => "application/json"}, ["Bad request"]]
# or
[404, {"Content-type" => "application/xml"}, ["Bad request"]]
```

However what I need is only to convert that string `to_json` and `to_xml`? **How is it possible do that?**

Comment: I'm confused. What sort of a result are you looking for in something like "Bad request".to_json? You can turn a hash into a JSON or XML string but it doesn't seem to make sense to turn a string by itself into JSON or XML.

Comment: You are right. I will update the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes you must add a `require 'json'` in your file (after installing the gem, [JSON implementation for Ruby](http://flori.github.com/json/) ) and do:

```
JSON.parse("Bad request").to_json
```

or you could try:

```
ActiveSupport::JSON.encode("Bad request").to_json
```

But in your case maybe the best approach is respond correctly:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @somearray }
  format.json  { render :json => @somearray }
end
```

Alternatively you could do:

```
  mystring_json = '{"bar":"foo"}'
  [404, {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'}, [mysrting_json]] #json stuff
  mystring_xml = '<?xml><bar>foo</bar>'
  [404, {'Content-Type' => 'application/xml'}, [mysrting_xml]]  #xml stuff
```

Answer (score 2):

In your controller, just pass in the XML string:

`render xml: "<myxml><cool>fff</cool></myxml>"`

Answer (score 1):

JSON follows JavaScript syntax, so a string in JSON is easy:

```
[404, {"Content-type" => "application/json"}, ["'Bad request'"]]
```

As for XML, the answer is not so simple. You'd have to decide what tag structure you want to use and go from there. Remember that an XML doc has, at a minimum, a root tag. So, you could return an XML doc like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<response>Bad request</response>
```

One way to do this would be to use the Builder gem:

http://builder.rubyforge.org/

However, I'm not entirely certain why you would need to return a string all by itself as JSON or XML. JSON and XML are typically used for transmitting structured data, e.g. arrays, nested data, key-value pairs, etc.. Whatever your client is, it could presumably just interpret the string as-is, without any JSON or XML ecoding, no?